# jQuery - moving image to the left on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code is not working in two ways.  it is not moving to the left after every click like it should (did i declare the position : relative correctly?), and also the delay for the left animation is 1 second, but the fade effect should only be set to 100.  however, the fade is also taking 1000 .  Thanks in advance and here is my code:

```
<html>
<center>
    <img src="image1.jpg" id="a1"></img>
    <br>
    <h1>it worked.</h1>
    <br>

    <img src="image2.jpg" width="500" height="500" id="a2" style="position:relative"></img>
</center>

</html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var x = .99;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("h1").hide();


        $("#a2").click(function () {

            if (x > .15) {
                x -= .1
                $("#a1").animate({
                    "left": "+=1000px"
                }, 1000);
                $("#a1").fadeTo(100, x);

            } else {
                $("h1").show(10);
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `</img>` tag and please stop using the `<center>` tag.

Comment: The ID and NAME elements must start with a letter i.e. upper case A to Z or lower case a to z; a number is not allowed. After the first letter any number of letters (a to z, A to Z), digits (0 to 9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:) and periods (.) are allowed.  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/valid-characters-html-id-attribute/

Comment: thanks for the advice, i edited my code, but yet still not wroking

Comment: If you want it to go to left, you should decrease left. left:0 is the left side of your screen...

Comment: i see, i will work with the details once i get it moving onclick

Comment: A similar question is [here][1]

Hope it may help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915291/move-image-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"left" css property applies only to the elements which are non-statically positioned. So please check this - add style position relative to your first image:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="a1" style="position:relative" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/57nZp/

Comment: thank you, i just had it added to the wrong image :O